# Titanium Appcelerator does not recognize my android devices

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Appcelerator Studio stopped recognizing my android devices. 
I try in all usb ports, changing the cable and all that with no efects.
After that, I made a titanium clean installation and it did not work either.

Any sugestions will be apretiate.
Thanks in advance.

Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 5.0.0.
SDK 7.0.1
MacOS 10.3.2

Comment: Can you build the application for Android? Also did you try using ADB to see if it can detect the devices without using Studio?

Comment: Hi @Soumya, no, i cant build the app for android, and the ADB do detect the device: build-tools $ /Users/salinasj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached
FA5BXB001492 device

Comment: Can you share the last few lines during the build process? Also does it work from the command line using appc?

Comment: Hi @Soumya, sorry.... how can i use the appc command to compile ?

Comment: Try this command, appc --build-only --platforms android --project-dir /path/to/project. You can also refer this link ::: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference

Comment: The project compile with no problem.  [INFO]  Performed build only, skipping installing of the application
[INFO]  Project built successfully in 1m 344ms

Comment: Still no work and i was playing with all the solutions that i found... any ideas?